# Bootstrap toggle switch onclick in Spring

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring

I am unable to fire onclick event after i click confirm on the pop up when i click the toggle switch. Anybody know what i wrong with it?

View

```
<td><a onclick="return confirmDelete(this, '<c:url value='active-user-${user.name}' />')"><input id="activeSwitch" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Active" data-off="InActive" data-onstyle="danger" data-width="90" data-height="30" type="checkbox"></a></td>
```

Script

```
 function confirmDelete(delForm, delUrl) {
                var stateValue = $("#tblClient #activeSwitch").is(":checked");

                if (confirm("Do you want to inActive this user?")) {
                            delForm.href = delUrl;          
                            elForm.submit();

                            return true; 
                        }

                        $('#tblClient #activeSwitch').bootstrapSwitch('toggleState', true, true);
                            return false;

                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning the function in the HTML?
You don't need to return the function. It's the function who returns something. So you just call the function normally without returning.

Comment: Returning to call out url

Comment: You can call it in the JS also.